# Issue while using kotlin reflaction to map object member properties to hashmap

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

```
open class Test {

    fun getAsHashMap() : HashMap<String, Any> {
        val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        val className = this.javaClass.kotlin

        for (prop in className::class.memberProperties) {
            val field = className::class.java.getDeclaredField(prop.name)
            val fieldSerializedName : SerializedName? = field.getAnnotation(SerializedName::class.java)
            fieldSerializedName?.let {
                hashMap[fieldSerializedName.value] = prop.get(this)!!
            } ?: run {
                hashMap[prop.name] = prop.get(this)!!
            }
        }

        return hashMap
    }


  }
```

I have wrote above function to map the memberProperties of `object instance` of its child class to `hashmap`. It either uses serialized name of the member or prop name [Based on availability of serialized name for that property]
But unfortunately I get the following error. 
[image: Error]
This is my first time using reflection java/kotlin, please let me know if it can be fixed.

Edit 1:

It works perfectly if I use name of the this.javaClass.kotlin directly like this

```
data class ProductInformation (
        @field:SerializedName("productid")
        val productId: Int,
        @field:SerializedName("productname")
        val productName: String,
        @field:SerializedName("brandname")
        val brandName: String,
        @field:SerializedName("originalprice")
        val originalPrice: Int,
        @field:SerializedName("sellingprice")
        val sellingPrice: Int,
        @field:SerializedName("productgender")
        val productGender: String,
        @field:SerializedName("productvariant")
        val productVariant: String,
        @field:SerializedName("discounted")
        val discounted: String,
        @field:SerializedName("productcategory")
        val productCategory: String
) : StructuredEventAttribute {

    override fun getAsHashMap(): HashMap<String, Any> {
        val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()

        for (prop in ProductInformation::class.memberProperties) {
            val field = ProductInformation::class.java.getDeclaredField(prop.name)
            val fieldSerializedName : SerializedName? = field.getAnnotation(SerializedName::class.java)
            fieldSerializedName?.let {
                hashMap[fieldSerializedName.value] = prop.get(this)!!
            } ?: run {
                hashMap[prop.name] = prop.get(this)!!
            }
        }

        return hashMap
    }

}

interface StructuredEventAttribute {
    fun getAsHashMap() : HashMap<String, Any>
}
```

It works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProductInformation::class.memberProperties` returns a collection of `ProductInformation` class member properties.

`className::class.memberProperties` (where `className = this.javaClass.kotlin`) returns a collection of member properties of class of `className`, which is `KClass<out Test>`. In short you are getting members of `KClass` instead of `Test`.

Solution: change `className::class.memberProperties` to `className.memberProperties`.